# Tab focused event in Lightning Console with Visualforce page

Tags: lightning, console

I have a Visualforce page that can be displayed pretty much everywhere (tab in classic, console, lightning console, lightning experience).

I have some visualisation issues when using the lightning console when the user switch to another tab and then back again to my page. I can resolve this issue by running some code when the tab get focused. The thing is, I can't find an API that works for me.

I found this: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_events_tabfocused.htm
But not sure even how to integrate it to my VF (the VF is not a lightning component).

Any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Your link is to the Lightning equivalents of the Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit APIs that have been available for many years for use in Visualforce pages.

There isn't an `onTabFocused` function but I see there is a [onEnclosingTabRefresh](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_onenclosingtabrefresh.htm?search_text=tabFocused) that may be the nearest thing. The sample code for that is:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/43.0/integration.js"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var eventHandler = function eventHandler(result) {
        alert('Enclosing tab has refreshed:' + result.id 
        + 'and the object Id is:' + result.objectId);
    };
    sforce.console.onEnclosingTabRefresh(eventHandler);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't seem to work. When trying to register the event handler, I'm getting the following error:
onEnclosingTabRefresh: Cannot get workspace from frameId: ext-comp-1005

Comment: @Shai OK, looks like that API is broken when the VF is in the Lightning Console and the Lightning API is hard/impossible to call... Hopefully someone else has a solution.